# Gaussian Process Help

Tags: gaussian-process

[image: Gaussian Regression]

How does each observation have a mean and standard deviation?  Are there multiple observations at each point to derive a Gaussian distribution at each point?

Secondly, how does a Gaussian regression draw a non-linear line between each dot?

Comment: Where is that data from? is it from Rasmussen book?

Comment: It's from the python library sckitlearn, located in their documentation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html